# nginx + fpm wanring about buffer size

Tags: nginx, buffer, php

We have a setup with nginx and fpm running on a ubuntu server.

When having long urls we get the following error in the php-fpm error log.

[17-Jul-2013 10:16:26] WARNING: [pool staging.local.me] child 19017 said into stderr: "NOTICE: the log buffer is full (1024). The access log request has been truncated."

My question is how can I increase the buffer size so that we do not get WARNINGS about these?

-S.

Answer (score 1):

This limit is coming from `php-fpm` (the "child") and not from `nginx`.

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1ad08256f349fa513157437abc4feb245cce03fc/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_log.c#L153

So to get rid of it, `php-fpm` needs to be recompiled...

The `buffer=32k` is doing something else: logs will be written out in 32k chunks,
not line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try increasing the buffer size with Nginx. The manual has mentioned this here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule

```
access_log  /spool/logs/nginx-access.log  gzip  buffer=32k;
```